# Do compiled expression trees leak?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, expression, expression-trees

In my understanding, JIT-ed code never gets released from memory while the program is running. Does this mean that repeatedly calling `.Compile()` on expression trees leaks memory?

The implication of that would be to only compile expression trees in static constructors or cache them in some other way, which may not be as simple. Right?

Comment: Why would you repeatedly compile the same expression? Maybe provide some code example?

Comment: Why assume the `.Compile()` is on the same the expression tree?

Comment: @Evk Because sometimes you don't cache them in a `Dictionary<>`, or in a static variable... It is an interesting question.

Comment: I don't have a code example and I don't believe it is needed. The question is whether compiling an expression tree irreversibly takes away some memory. Which should mean developers need to be careful about generating and compiling a new tree every time a user types something in a text box, for instance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are probably GCed... [`LambdaExpression.Compile()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/LambdaExpression.cs#L128) uses the [`LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression, DebugInfoGenerator)`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs#L200) class, that [through one of the `LambdaCompiler` constructors](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs#L87) uses [`DynamicMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) that, from MSDN:

> Defines and represents a dynamic method that can be compiled, executed, and discarded. **Discarded methods are available for garbage collection.**

Comment: So compiled expressions are not GC'ed? It reads like only discarded expressions are GC'ed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is the opposite... They **are** GCed... For "dicarded" I think they mean "not anymore referenced". There is no "Discard()" method anywhere, so any other reading of the description would be meaningless.

Answer (score 13):

I tried testing this by continuously generating a expression trees in the background and then collecting all garbage and monitoring used space in the GUI thread.

It would seem memory usage stays steady at around 655000 bytes after a couple of hours. So I'd say it's safe to go wild with expression trees.

[image: Expression tree memory usage]

If anyone wants my hacky test code, here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Experiments
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Ensuring that always the same amount of memory is used for point storage.
            bytesUsed = new Queue<long>(1000);
            var points = chart1.Series[0].Points;
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            {
                bytesUsed.Enqueue(0);
                points.Add(0);
            }


            thread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
            thread.Start();
            timer1.Interval = 10000;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1_Tick(null, null);
        }

        private readonly Queue<long> bytesUsed;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();

            bytesUsed.Dequeue();
            bytesUsed.Enqueue(GC.GetTotalMemory(false));

            var points = chart1.Series[0].Points;
            points.Clear();
            foreach (var value in bytesUsed)
                points.Add(value);
        }

        private Thread thread;
        private volatile bool stopping;
        private void ThreadMethod()
        {
            var random = new Random();

            while (!stopping)
            {
                var constant = Expression.Constant(random.Next(), typeof(int));
                var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

                var mul = Expression.Multiply(param, constant);
                var add = Expression.Multiply(mul, param);
                var sub = Expression.Subtract(add, constant);

                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(sub, param);
                var compiled = lambda.Compile();
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            stopping = true;
            if (thread != null && disposing)
                thread.Join();

            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```