# Does Blazor WebAssembly suffer memory leaks from compiled lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, blazor, blazor-webassembly

We have a Blazor WebAssembly app, compiled on .NET 6.0, whose memory keeps increasing until it hits the 2 GB limit, then silently crashes. We've narrowed down the main cause of the leak to [compiled lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1?view=net-6.0). I've seen that compiled lambda expressions [shouldn't cause memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43041190/14207973) on .NET proper. Is this a known issue in Blazor WebAssembly?

The following code may be used to reproduce the memory leak. It can be wired up as the event handler of a button on a page. When left running in the active tab (in the foreground), it leaks around 46 MB of memory a minute, causing the 2 GB limit to be reached (and the app to crash) in 47 minutes.

```cs
private async Task RunMemoryLeakTestAsync()
{
    long total = 0;

    for (long i = 0; i < 2_000_000_000; i++)
    {
        Expression<Func<long, long>> expression = x => x + x;
        var func = expression.Compile();
        total += func(i);

        if (i % 1_000 == 0)
            await Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay: 100);  // keep app responsive and give GC time to run
    }
}
```

[image: Chrome Memory]

**Edit**: I've also [opened an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/82716) under dotnet / runtime in GitHub to draw Microsoft's attention to this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That link only discusses memory leaks arising when one calls .NET from JavaScript. I'm not using `DotNetObjectReference` in my code.

Comment: What happens if you call `GC.Collect` after your delay? Also see [workstation vs server GC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/workstation-server-gc).

Comment: @ConnorLow: Memory leak still occurs like before (even with `GC.Collect` before the delay, and even with `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` in between). Note that this is Blazor WebAssembly, which uses a different .NET runtime (and GC implementation) than the traditional ones discussed in that article.